# select column names whose entries are value 1

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve columns name from table whose value is 1

My query is give below...

```
mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_therapist_schedule` WHERE `schedule_date`='30.11.2017'");
```

My table structure is give below...

```
slot1 slot2 slot3
  1     1    0
  2     1    1
  1     1    2
  3     1    0
```

my result...

slot1 slot2 slot3

Comment: I have 4 rows on that date

Comment: We are unable to view these rows can you add sample data alongwith your expected resultset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the serious feeling that your data is not normalized.  Instead of having separate columns for each slot, I would store all this data in a single column with metadata to relate each slot's state.

That being said, one way to get the output you want would be to aggregate over each slot column and check for the presence/absence of at least one `1` value.  I then use `GROUP_CONCAT` to generate a CSV list of matching slots.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(slots)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN slot1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'slot1' END AS slots
    FROM tbl_therapist_schedule
    WHERE schedule_date = '30.11.2017'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN slot2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'slot2' END
    FROM tbl_therapist_schedule
    WHERE schedule_date = '30.11.2017'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN slot3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'slot3' END
    FROM tbl_therapist_schedule
    WHERE schedule_date = '30.11.2017'
) t;
```

### Demo

Comment: Change your table design and puts slots into columns instead of rows.

Comment: ok, thank u very much... but i can't change my table structure

Comment: 50 columns means 50 separate aggregations AFAIK.  No avoiding this, hence the suggestions to store slots columnwise.